# SharePoint 2010 NewForm.aspx Lookup Fields Issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, wss, sharepoint-list, lookupfield

I have a SharePoint 2010 Foundation site that has recently been upgraded from WSS 3.0.  The upgrade was completed successfully with no glitches.

However, ever since I have upgraded the site I have got a problem relating to lookup fields on the NewForm.aspx (New list entry page) on some calendar lists that were existing on the site prior to the upgrade.

The issue is that I have two lookup fields, one for **Client** and another for **Meeting Type / Location**.  When I am on the NewForm.aspx (new list item entry page) and I select an entry in one of the lookup fields the second doesn’t allow me to select anything and just gives me the top value in the lookup list without offering any other alternative selections like it should.  These fields are just standard SharePoint Lookup fields and are not modified in any way, nor is the page.  This problem does not happen on new lists I create (with more than one lookup field in them) in the site nor does it happen if I add extra lookup fields on the existing lists, it just leaves these two fields with issues.

I have used Internet Explorers debugging tools to see if there is an error in any of the JavaScript on the page but nothing is being reported as being a problem and I have also tried rendering the page in different standards in Internet Explorer to see if it is related to the browser but these do not many any difference.  One thing that is apparent though is that the values for both lookup fields are being pulled in to the HTML of the page as I can see them when viewing the HTML source of the page when it has loaded and in the Developer Tools in Internet Explorer…

If anyone has any experience of things like this and could point me in the direction of a fix for this I would be very grateful...

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these two links.  This first might be your issue and while the fix was included on August 2012 CU you still have to make a manual edit (not a true fix in my book)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2598273 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2687375